# Why *all* the resistances of the bridge need to be of the same order for maximum sensitivity?

Tags: experimental-physics

Consider the following Wheatstone bridge.

[image]

I understand that for maximum sensitivity of the bridge (*at the balance point*), the ratio of $P$ to $Q$ must be $1$. A derivation of this can be found [here](https://www.electricalengineeringinfo.com/2016/10/measurement-of-medium-resistance-by-wheatstone-bridge.html).

But almost everywhere on the internet, it is mentioned that the bridge is most sensitive when *all* of $P,Q, S$ are of the same order as of $R$ (the unknown resistance.

**Question:** Is that correct? If so, why?

Comment: Well, derive conditions with, say, R being much larger .

Comment: Even if R and S are both very large but their ratio is 1 (equal to that of P and Q) I still can't see how this would affect sensitivity.